# Save aspx page as pdf

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I want to save aspx page as pdf file like google chrome(like picture). how can i do this ?

[image: save as PDF]

Answer (score -1):

Chrome uses the open source [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).  If you're using mvc I would recomend [rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/1.7.3), which wraps the calls to wkhtmltopdf giving you

```
return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Giorgio" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
```

if you're using vanilla asp.net you can post the raw html or a link back to the server and shell out to the wkhtmltopdf command line and generate a pdf.  If you're sending a link back you'll have to handle authentication as the command line app will not automatically authenticate as your user.

Comment: I converted only div with iTextSharp but the page is broken. Are there any solutions with iTextSharp?

Comment: Are you loading in all the css?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41341398/itextsharp-add-css-style-or-a-css-file-and-download-pdf-file

Comment: If you want to use iText then don't use iText 5 + XMLWorker, but use iText 7 + pdfHTML instead. iTextSharp is the old name for iText .NET.

Comment: I don't understand how this "answer" answers the question.

Comment: The image was added after I answered (or I completely missed it)

Comment: The image was always there. Initially as an external link, easy to overlook, and then it was made inline.

Comment: @MiniverCheevy I didn't use any css when I create html page. So I should add which css file?

Comment: @can what do thou mean by the page is broken?

Comment: it must be display like; https://i.hizliresim.com/GyqG02.png 
But it display like ; https://i.hizliresim.com/nJvyW0.png @MiniverCheevy

Comment: that really seems css related (background colors, borders, images sizes).  If you <CTRL>+P the page does it look like the 2nd image?  How did you apply the background color and borders?  Was it inline styles?