# how to give boder colors in html table without using style tags

Tags: html, user-interface

I need to develop some example without using styles tags, i tried mostly, but i am unable to add border and border specific td borders please see my code and help me on this.

```
<table style="width:100%" border='0' cellpadding="0" ><tr cellspacing="0">
<td rowspan='2' > <img  height='100' width='80' src="http://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg" alt=" Logo" /></td>
<td width='500' border='1' bordercolor="red"><b>some text</b></td></tr><tr cellspacing="0">
<td border='1' color='red' >some text
                  </td>
<td> <label> Name: &nbsp;</label><br />
                <label>class: &nbsp;</label><br />
                <label>  ID: &nbsp;</label></td></tr></table>
```

Output look like this: 
[image: Output look]

Comment: Can you use classes or IDs? Attributes like `border` and similars you are using are all deprecated

Comment: There's a reason why you don't use CSS file?

Comment: @Gonzalo yes, i am generating pdf using itextsharp, in that inline styles are not recognising, so need to develop like this only, i have option is loadstyles but it is effecting remaining pdf. So please help me on this output without style keyword (inline style)

Comment: @Daniel class is also fine. Will you please help me on this output

Comment: If you can use classes then it will more simple with help of internal style and it will work when you generate PDF file or you want simple by html then use **bordercolor="#ff0000"** in table.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam yes, but i am unable to  create that exact output

Comment: some classes  are not working in pdf like class='table table-bordered', thats the main reason i need table without style tags like padding-top,margin-top etc

Comment: @RaeeshAlam please run my code then only you find the problem, i am not getting borders becuase i added border='0' while creating a table. see the above code once

Comment: @chaitanya **class='table table-bordered'** this is predefined classes in *bootstrap* so if you want exact in pdf then you need to find a way for how to include css file when PDF generate time.

Comment: @chaitanya Also need to change html **table structure** if as you want look like attachment image. I am adding a snippet for this attachment image with html table structure change and use internal style.

Comment: Did you tried any of these solutions? [iTextSharp add ( css style or a css file) and download pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41341398/itextsharp-add-css-style-or-a-css-file-and-download-pdf-file) or [itextsharp - CSS not getting applied - C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321779/itextsharp-css-not-getting-applied-c-sharp-net/5322787)

Answer (score 0):

Use **internal style** with help of classes if support your `PDF generation tool` inside internal style.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.my-table{border-collapse:separate;width:100%;}
.my-table td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
/*Below border color defined*/
.border-black{border-color: #000000;}
.border-green{border-color: #00ff00;}
.border-red{border-color: #ff0000;}
.border-blue{border-color: #0000ff;}
/*Below text color defined*/
.text-green{color: #00ff00;}
</style>

<table class="my-table" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="border-red" rowspan="2" width="80">
     <img  height='100' width='80' src="http://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg" alt=" Logo" />
    </td>
    <td class="border-black text-green">Some text with black border and green text color</td>
    <td class="border-blue" rowspan="2">
     <label>Name: &nbsp;</label><br />
        <label>Class: &nbsp;</label><br />
        <label>ID: &nbsp;</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-green text-green" width="400">
     Some text with green border & green text color
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```